# Increment Row Number on Group for regular withdrawal amounts

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to create a SQL Server query which groups together "common" sequential data and assigns a unique id to the group.  In the example below I have withdrawals made from a policy on a somewhat regular basis.

```
create table #Temp2 (Policy_Id int, WDL_Date int, Amount decimal(9,2));

insert into #Temp2 values(1001, 19881028, 190.00);
insert into #Temp2 values(1001, 19881129, 190.00);
insert into #Temp2 values(1001, 19881229, 494.89);
insert into #Temp2 values(1001, 19890130, 494.89);
insert into #Temp2 values(1001, 19890227, 494.89);
insert into #Temp2 values(1001, 19890330, 494.89);
insert into #Temp2 values(1001, 19890530, 525.00);
insert into #Temp2 values(1001, 19890629, 525.00);
insert into #Temp2 values(1001, 19890728, 525.00);
insert into #Temp2 values(1001, 19890830, 525.00);
insert into #Temp2 values(1001, 19930723, 51.00);
insert into #Temp2 values(1001, 19931213, 190.00);
insert into #Temp2 values(1001, 19940311, 190.00);
insert into #Temp2 values(1001, 19940613, 190.00);

insert into #Temp2 values(1002, 19881028, 50.00);
insert into #Temp2 values(1002, 19881129, 50.00);
insert into #Temp2 values(1002, 19881229, 60.00);
insert into #Temp2 values(1002, 19890130, 100.00);
insert into #Temp2 values(1002, 19890227, 100.00);
```

I would like to create output such as that below where column Id is populated by the query. Note that the amounts are sorted in date order which should determine the values in the field Id.

```
Policy_Id   WDL_Date    Amount  Id
---------   --------    ------  --
1001        19881028    190.00  1   
1001        19881129    190.00  1
1001        19881229    494.89  2
1001        19890130    494.89  2
1001        19890227    494.89  2
1001        19890330    494.89  2
1001        19890530    525.00  3
1001        19890629    525.00  3
1001        19890728    525.00  3   
1001        19890830    525.00  3
1001        19930723    51.00   4
1001        19931213    190.00  5
1001        19940311    190.00  5
1001        19940613    190.00  5

1002        19881028    50.00   1
1002        19881129    50.00   1
1002        19881229    60.00   2
1002        19890130    100.00  3
1002        19890227    100.00  3
```

I've tried using DENSE_RANK() to populate Id but the problem I encounter is that the 2 separate grouped amounts for 190.00 (top 2 and bottom 3 records for Policy_Id = 1001) need to be kept separate and the DENSE_RANK() statement considers both groups of 190.00 as 1 group.  I also need the grouping to restart at each new policy. This is my code which doesn't produce the required output.

```
select *,
       DENSE_RANK() over (order by policy_id, amount) as Id
from
    #Temp2
order by policy_id, WDL_Date;
```

Can anyone provide any guidance on this?

Comment: How do you uniquely identify the different groups? How do you determine that the top 2 amounts of 190 do not belong to the bottom 3?

Comment: The above example includes regular withdrawals from an account in date order. The top 2 amounts of 190.00 are grouped together because the withdrawal amount was the same for a period of time ... could be many mths but in this case was only 2 mths. There was then a change of amount in date order which signals the start of the next group. In effect, the Id changes on the change of Amount in WDL_Date order.

Answer (score 0):

To get all 190.00s together You will need to do something like this...

```
SELECT *,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY policy_id ORDER BY amount) as Id
FROM
    #Temp2
ORDER BY policy_id, ID;
```

Your desired output has some discrepancies as when you order by amount in your ranking function value 51.00 should be the first value not 190.00